# Can I submit an apps to the Apple App Store using Mac OS yosemite under VMWare?

Tags: app-store, vmware

My question is why does the hardware matter? What information is iTunes connect pulling that indicates it is Apple hardware? And how would it recognize that it is a VM running in a VM on a PC, running in a VM on a Mac?

Just curious.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a programming question within the scope defined in the [help]

Answer (score 0):

Why should that matter? It will probably work.

Also, why don't you just try that and if it does not work then go get a Mac or upload from some friends Apple computer.

Answer (score -1):

It's worth it to get an iMac to develop for iOS or OS X.

Get a used iMac Mini.  I developed my first app on a 2011 MacBook Air with 4 GB. Mac Minis also do a good job. I'd recommend getting at least 8 GB these days.

Check a few online sources to get a feel for prices:

http://www.ebay.com/bhp/mac-mini

http://www.ebay.com/bhp/imac-27

Apple also sells refurbished iMacs:

http://store.apple.com/ca/browse/home/specialdeals/mac/imac

Apple computers hold their value well so you can always sell it when you are done.

Wish you success with your app. You'll find the building it was the fun and easy part.  Marketing it is the real challenge.